# Delete a row once it is used

Tags: python

I have a CSV with 500k rows. Currently I only need to use one value from the file and I am able to get that. What I would like to do is once the value is used to delete the row, is this possible?

Here is my current code:

```
import csv
import os

def getvin():
    linenumber = 1
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ITRACK6VIN.csv'), 'rb') as csvfile:
        vinreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        myvins = list(vinreader)
        text = myvins[linenumber][0]
        return text

print getvin()
```

Comment: you can't delete from the middle of a file, you have to read the file and write it back out to remove data from it

Comment: Do you want to grab a vin number, do something with it, then grab the next one? If so, there are better ways to iterate through the vin number list then reading the 2nd line, deleting it, reading the new 2nd line, deleting it, and so on... such as `for line in vinreader: vin = line[0]`.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I am not removing from the middle of the file. The only row which will ever be used is the first row. So basically the test will get the first row, use it, and then delete the first row.

Comment: I would like to put -1 to person who flagged the question as "simple typo error".

Comment: @Bill yes I want to grab a VIN and then on the next test run grab the next VIN and so on. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Is there a typo error?

Comment: @DarthOpto No, there isn't. The guy who puts the flag just doesn't know how works StackOverflow I guess :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DarthOpto, if you want to iterate through the vin numbers, then you can do something like

```
import csv
import os

def process_vins():
    vin_numbers = []
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ITRACK6VIN.csv'), 'r') as csvfile:
        vinreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        vinreader.next() # skip the first row, presumably a header
        for row in vinreader: # iterate through each row in the file
            current_vin = row[0] # access the first element of the row
            current_vin = modify_vin(current_vin) # optional, do something with vin
            vin_numbers.append(current_vin) # store vins in a list

    return vin_numbers # return that list

process_vins()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
import csv
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ITRACK6VIN.csv'), 'rb') as csvfile:
    vinreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in vinreader:
        print line[0]
```